# Trying to check the item already printed and print items other than that

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to check with a conditional the item already printed and print items other than the one already shown? I am trying to give other breweries as recommendations. I suppose there is a way to check it but I'm still learning React and not sure how to do it.

```
import React from "react";
import './DetailPage.css'

class DetailPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: [],
      brewery: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    fetch(`https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries/${id}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          brewery: data
        });
      });
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({
            breweries: data,
          })
        })
  }

  render() {
    const { brewery } = this.state;
    return(
    <div className="background">
      <div className="details">
          <p>Name: {brewery.name}</p>
          <p>Category: {brewery.brewery_type}</p>
          <p>Address: {brewery.street}, {brewery.city}, {brewery.state}, {brewery.postal_code}, {brewery.country}</p>
          <p>Phone Number: {brewery.phone}</p>
          <p>Website: <a href={brewery.website_url} target="_blank">{brewery.website_url}</a></p>
      </div>
      <div className="recommendations">Recommendations</div>
      <div>
      <div className="row">
        {this.state.breweries.slice(0.10).map((brewery, i) =>
          <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" key={i}>
              <div className="card">
                <div className="card-description">
                  <h2>{brewery.brewery_type}</h2>
                  <p>{brewery.city}, {brewery.state}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="card-category">{brewery.name}</div>
              </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DetailPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filtered array and then map over and render that instead... This should work:

```
import React from 'react';

class DetailPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: [],
      brewery: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    fetch(`https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries/${id}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          brewery: data,
        });
      });
    fetch('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { brewery } = this.state;
    const { id } = brewery; // here we get the id
    const breweries = this.state.breweries.filter(brewery => brewery.id !== id); // and here is where we create a filtered version of the state
    return (
      <div className="background">
        <div className="details">
          <p>Name: {brewery.name}</p>
          <p>Category: {brewery.brewery_type}</p>
          <p>
            Address: {brewery.street}, {brewery.city}, {brewery.state}, {brewery.postal_code}, {brewery.country}
          </p>
          <p>Phone Number: {brewery.phone}</p>
          <p>
            Website:
            <a
              href={brewery.website_url}
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              {brewery.website_url}
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="recommendations">Recommendations</div>
        <div>
          <div className="row">
            {breweries.map(brewery => ( // and here is wehere we iterate over the filtered array
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" key={brewery.id}>
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-description">
                    <h2>{brewery.brewery_type}</h2>
                    <p>
                      {brewery.city}, {brewery.state}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-category">{brewery.name}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DetailPage;
```

Live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/189998yvw3)

Comment: So I was supposed to filter it... Works well, thanks a lot

Comment: Consider the following: not filtering entire `this.state.breweries` array but adding condition into `map` function callback to check the same you check in filter function.

Comment: @Vadim :) I was going to 'chain' them but thought this would be clearer...